# Read PDF and Output in PictureBox using C#

Tags: c#, pdf, picturebox

I'm using C# 2005 as a programming platform. I want to have a program reading pdf file and output the content in picturebox properties. Can anyone help me on how could i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some opensource libraries out there. Choose one of the below:

sharpPDF: http://sharppdf.sourceforge.net/

PDFjet: http://pdfjet.com/os/edition.html

PDF Clown: http://sourceforge.net/projects/clown/

You can get the content of the PDF file using on of these libraries. About showing it on your form etc., I'd suggest examining the samples of these libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You can't render PDF in a PictureBox. Picture boxes are for displaying pictures. So if you want to render a PDF file inside a picture box you will have to first convert it to, well, a picture. There are some commercial products such as ABC PDF that would allow you to do this conversion.

Another possibility is to [use the Adobe Reader ActiveX control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220134/displaying-a-pdf-file-from-winform) which you could host in your WinForms application and directly show the PDF file as is.